# UPSERT using InnoDB engine?

Tags: php, mysql

Here is the solution for an UPSERT that uses primary key idfill to check for duplicates.  I'm just not sure if it's sql injection proof or even efficient?

```
$idq="SELECT idafill FROM afillInfo, actorsInfo
WHERE (actorsInfo.id = afillInfo.id_actor) AND email = '$_SESSION[email]'" or die    (mysql_error());



$sql = "INSERT INTO afillInfo (idfill, agency, agentPhone, afillChoice, id_actor)
VALUES ( ?,?,?,?, ( select id FROM actorsInfo WHERE email = ?))
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
`id_actor` = VALUES(`id_actor`),
`agency` = VALUES(`agency`),
`agentPhone` = VALUES(`agentPhone`),
`afillChoice` = VALUES(`afillChoice`)
";


if (($stmt = $con->prepare($sql)) === false) {
trigger_error($con->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}

$result= mysqli_query($con, $idq);
$row_number = 1;
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

$idfill= $row["idafill"];
}

if ($stmt->bind_param("sssss",
$idfill,
$_POST["agency"], $_POST["agentPhone"],
$_POST["afillChoice"], $_SESSION["email"]) === false) {
trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}


if (($stmt->execute()) === false) {
trigger_error($stmt->error, E_USER_ERROR);
}
```

Comment: Upsert? Insert or Update?

Comment: Not related to your question, but it is unsafe to interpolate $_POST variables directly into your SQL statement.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Thanks I will fix that later.

Comment: I always just used 'replace into' for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

INSERT adds a new row if it can.

When you use INSERT...ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, it performs an UPDATE **only** if your INSERT would create a duplicate value in a primary key or unique key column.

Thank you for posting your table definition. I see now that you have no UNIQUE column besides `idfill`, the primary key.

So if you don't specify a value for idfill, it'll generate a new value in a new row. There's no way this will trigger the duplicate key. It makes no sense to run the query as you are doing and not expect it to create a new row.

You must specify an existing value in your INSERT statement for a PRIMARY or UNIQUE KEY, in order to cause the INSERT to fail and fall through to do the UPDATE. Otherwise the INSERT will succeed, by creating a new row with a distinct value for the primary key.

So you must add the idfill column to your INSERT, and specify a value that conflicts with one already existing in the database.

```
INSERT INTO afillInfo (idfill, agency, agentPhone, afillChoice, id_actor)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ( SELECT id FROM actorsInfo WHERE email = ?))
   ...
```

---

Apologies that I didn't notice this immediately, but another problem is that the UPDATE part of your statement *isn't changing anything*.

```
        ... UPDATE
`id_actor` = `id_actor`,
`agency` = `agency`,
`agentPhone` = `agentPhone`,
`afillChoice` = `afillChoice`
```

This sets the columns to exactly the same values they had before. It's a no-op. It's the equivalent of doing this in PHP:

```
$sql = $sql;
```

You can work around this by using the VALUES() function to re-use the values you tried to insert. Here's an example:

```
        ... UPDATE
`id_actor` = VALUES(`id_actor`),
`agency` = VALUES(`agency`),
`agentPhone` = VALUES(`agentPhone`),
`afillChoice` = VALUES(`afillChoice`)
```

Comment: I made some changes can you take a look at what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks.  Aside from a missing parantheses I managed to get it to insert but the update is still behaving the same way as before. you mention to add idfill into the on duplicate key update.  How do I add this primary key reference?

Comment: Thanks. I tried the new version and after deleting sss params to fit the latest modification, it still adds another line even with all of the fields duplicated.

Comment: Please edit your question above to include the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE aFillInfo`.

Comment: I included the SHOW CREATE TABLE afillInfo.  Hope this helps. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  It finaly works but I'm not sure if it's SQL injection proof?

Comment: In the first query, use a parameter instead of interpolating $_SESSION[email] into the string.